# Add hostname to monitor MongoDB Replica Set in Icinga2

Tags: mongodb, icinga2

I have a distributed Mongodb setup and I'm trying to configure it with **Icinga2** using the following link as reference,

https://admin-docs.com/databases/mongodb/mongodb-administration/monitor-mongodb-using-icinga/

As mine is a distributed setup, Icinga should connect to Mongodb along with hostname parameter as,

```
mongo -h ipaddress
```

Without this, Icinga2 dashboard shows the following error for all the MongoDB monitoring services,

> CRITICAL - Connection to Mongo server on 127.0.0.1:27017 has failed

How do I configure my Icinga2 setup to use hostname in the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, pretty simple, just had to set the variable value for mongodb_address using the following,

```
apply Service "Mongodb Connection" {
  check_command = "mongodb"
  command_endpoint = host.vars.client_endpoint
  vars.mongodb_address = "$address$"
  assign where host.vars.client_endpoint && host.vars.os == "MongoOnLinux"
}
```

Here, *$address$* is in built variable for host IP Address